# Why use an additional List (or array) inside a custom-adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I have asked myself the above question and did not come to a real solution so far.

Below you can see **two implementations of a custom adapter** for a `ListView` holding `Strings`. The first implementation uses an **additional list** of values inside the `Adapter`, like it is also done in many `ListView` tutorials I have seen. (e.g. [vogella-listview-tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_example))

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> mList;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List< String > objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        mList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String item = mList.get(position);

        // ... do stuff ...

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The second implementation below simply uses the `List` of `Strings` that has already been handed to the `Adapter`, and does not need an additional List. Instead, the `Adapters` `getItem(int pos)` method is used:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List< String > objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String item = getItem(position);

        // ... do stuff ...

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now my question:

**What is the reason** for using an **additional** `List` inside a `CustomAdapter` when you can simply use the adapters `getItem(int pos)` method and spare the additional `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are extending `ArrayAdapter` that extends `BaseAdapter` you do not need to have a copy of the dataset, but providing it to the `super` is enough. If you extends another adapter, `BaseAdapter` you have to override

1. `getCount()`
2. `getItem(int)`
3. `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`
4. `getItemId(int)`

all of the require to access to the dataset.

Comment: So what is done in the tutorial link I posted is actually not necessary? What about performance when e.g. using an array?

Comment: No is not necessary. Why are you worried about performances? Since you are extending `ArrayAdapter` I'll say that is better if you stick with `Collections (List)`, just because if you provide a List instance you can easily remove elements from the dataset

Comment: I am not worried, just curious. Thank you anyway.